# How to resolve crypto.getRandomValues() not supported?

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13, turbopack

After switching to turbopack i have following error:

https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported

Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding following code to `app\api\auth\[...nextauth]\route.ts` removed error.

```
import crypto from "node:crypto";
global.crypto ??= crypto;
```