# Firebase Admin Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I am using the Firebase Admin SDK in a next project. I have an api endpoint that needs to get a file from the firebase storage

```
const file = await getStorage().bucket().file(uid+"/sample.png").createReadStream()
```

When I run the code, this error appears:

> Error during SSR Rendering
> error rendering: Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported

I looked for the error message but it is always related to react native. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.
The same error occurs if I try download() instead of createReadStream()

Comment: PS: I also tried this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76294229/how-to-resolve-crypto-getrandomvalues-not-supported already but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but just in case is useful for someone, I solved this error by upgrading the functions to node js version 20.

Be sure to add this line on your `package.json` file inside the `functions` directory:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
```